# Writing for loop for list in tcl

Tags: tcl

Trying to use a for loop to do dft_scan_1 all the way to 163
Write now I have

```
For {set a 0} {$a < 164} {incr a}
```

Confused on where to go from here

Comment: You might find the [Tcl tutorial](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) helpful, particularlly https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl10.html

Answer (score 1):

You example so far is missing the body of the loop.

What are you doing with your variable for each iteration?

```
for {set a 0} {$a < 164} {incr a} {
    # body of loop here....
    puts "The value of a is $a"
}
```